# rename xml rootnode using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the below code to change the root node name. But its not working for me. Please help me to do this. My partial code is given below.

```
XmlNode PackageListNode = hst_doc.SelectSingleNode("NewDataSet");
                XmlNodeList PackageNodeList = PackageListNode.SelectNodes("Table5");

                hst_doc.DocumentElement.Name.Replace("NewDataSet", "rows");
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx

Follow this code:

```
XmlDocument objDoc = new XmlDocument();
objDoc.LoadXml(str);
XmlDocument objNewDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement objNewRoot = objNewDoc.CreateElement("MasterList");
objNewDoc.AppendChild(objNewRoot);
objNewRoot.InnerXml = objDoc.DocumentElement.InnerXml;
String xml = docNew.OuterXml;
```

Hope its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I belief you are not calling Save() method after changes try below code

```
        XmlNode PackageListNode = hst_doc.SelectSingleNode("NewDataSet");
        XmlNodeList PackageNodeList = PackageListNode.SelectNodes("Table5");

        hst_doc.DocumentElement.Name.Replace("NewDataSet", "rows");

        hst_doc.Save("filename");
```

Comment: I am using a xmldoumnet only

Comment: Not a XML file. I using a xmldocument

Comment: after modifying you need to save that document. save() is overloaded method chose as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// Obtain a document; this method is implemented in
// The Quintessential Program to Create a DOM Document from an XML File
Document doc = parseXmlFile("infilename.xml", false);


// Obtain the root element
Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();


// Create an element with the new name
Element element2 = doc.createElement("newname");


// Copy the attributes to the new element
NamedNodeMap attrs = element.getAttributes();
for (int i=0; i<attrs.getLength(); i++) {
    Attr attr2 = (Attr)doc.importNode(attrs.item(i), true);
    element2.getAttributes().setNamedItem(attr2);
}


// Move all the children
while (element.hasChildNodes()) {
    element2.appendChild(element.getFirstChild());
}


// Replace the old node with the new node
element.getParentNode().replaceChild(element2, element);
```

**Or Try This**

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
            doc.Root.Name = "program";
            doc.Save("output.xml");
```